# Есть ли возможность прогнать нативные es6 модули через babel?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babel, модули

На статичном сайте используются нативные es6 модули.

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

В отдельной сборке я хочу прогонять эти модули через babel для большей кроссбраузерности.

// webpack.config.js

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/i,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader'],
  }
]
```

// .babelrc

```
  {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "modules": false,
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
```

Я не хочу, чтобы babel превращал модули в commonjs и т.п., я просто хочу превратить остальной es6 в es2015

// main.js before

```
export default () => {
  return 'Hello world!'
}
```

// main.js after

```
export default function () {
  return 'Hello world!'
}
```

Согласно документации babel предоставляет опцию module: false, но она не работает у меня

По факту babel преобразовывает файл в нечто похожее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть он просто копирует импортируемые данные в скомпилированный файл.

При большом количестве файлов создает дополнительные чанки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли возможность просто проигнорировать импорты и экспорты при траспиляции в es5? Спасибо

Comment: Ну, самый простой вариант это перенести эти модули в подпапку (например, `modern/`) и добавить ее в `exclude` правила js-файлов. Насколько я понял ситуацию, тут html-loader эмитит эти модули, если они больше нигде не импортируются (то есть, проблема вероятно заключается не в бабелевском лодыре: он просто молотит то что ему дают, и надо всего лишь не давать ему "лишнее").

Comment: Так он же тогда вообще их не пропустит через себя? И в es5 не форматнет? Мне нужно, чтобы он эти модули превратил в es5, но не трогал import export в этих файлах.

Comment: Да, просто пропустит. Разве не это подразумевается под "просто проигнорировать при траспиляции в es5"? Ну если не это, то можно собрать все из этой подпапки в отдельный бандл - или это тоже неок вариант? :)

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю что все-таки требуется результатом получить: сначала написано что модули хочется транспайлить, затем написано что их надо проигнорировать... еще смущает момент про "импорты и экспорты", при том что в начале показано подключение тегом es-модуля (то есть в разметке, а не импортом).

Comment: У меня есть модули. Они между собой общаются через import export. Мне нужно прогнать код в этих модулях через Бабель. Но только, чтобы на выходе эти модули остались es6 модулями, а не превращались в common js.

Comment: Проигнорировать функционал import export в этих модулях, а не сами модули

Comment: Чтобы код внутри модуля: export const a = () => {} после babel преобразовался в export var a = function () {}

Comment: А, ясно. В package.json прописано `"type": "module"`? Если нет, попробуй добавить (не убирая опцию `modules` в конфиге бабеля) - это может помочь сохранить es-импорты. Вот по поводу того что вебпак отрыгивает кучу js-файлов, тут уж все непросто: надо смотреть как лоадеры настроены (если никак, то вполне естественно что сборщик создает чанк на каждый эмит js-модуля извлеченного из разметки. Мне все же кажется что это именно html-loader их выдирает, т.е. считаю что тут не получится обойтись без помещения в поддиректорию с правилом для file-loader'а или генератора ассетов. Хотя я не гуру вебпака)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129477/discussion-between-yar85-and-rinat-sadykov).